React Suspense causes lots of renders
I am lazy loading a component based on two ids that sit in the Context.
const LazyStuff = () => {

console.log('---LazyStuff---');

//this is the module (which is quite a complex object managed with useReducer)
const {
    isLoading: isLoadingModule,
    isError: isErrorModule,
    ...module
} = useModuleContext();

//this is a callback that sets the module in the context based on some URL parameters
const setModuleByLocation = useSetModuleByLocation(module.dispatch);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('---useEffect---');
    setModuleByLocation();
}, [setModuleByLocation]);

const Module = useMemo(
    () =>
        lazy(() =>
            import(`@modules/${module.id}/${module.mode.id}`).catch(() => ({
                default: () => null,
            }))
        ),
    [module.id, module.mode.id]
);

return (
  <Suspense fallback={<>Loading...</>}>
    <Module {...module} />
  </Suspense>
);
};

export const ModuleProvider = ({ children }) => {

  const reducer = (state, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {

            case 'SET_MODULE': 

            console.log('---SET_MODULE---');

            return {
                   ...state,
                   ...action.payload
                };

           default:
                return state;
        }
    };
    
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
     id: null,
     mode: {
       id: null
     }
   })
}

When I check the console, I see odd things:

'---useEffect---' is logged once as expected
'---LazyStuff---' is logged around 100 times (why???)
'---SET_MODULE---' is logged around 100 times (why???)

I do not understand why there are so many rerenders of the component LazyStuff and especially, why ---SET_MODULE--- is executed so many times when the useEffect that does the dispatch only runs once...
